# Outside the loop, how can I echo the current page's menu title?

Tags: menus

I have no idea why I'm finding this so hard. I've gone through many similar posts here, but none are working.

I am building a menu outside of the loop on my index page - it a standard posts page, not a static page set as home. Basically, I want the current page's menu title (ie: Home) to be echoed onto the page. I will put the same code on single/page/archive/etc. Then I'm using wp_nav_menu to echo out the menu beneath it, like so:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => 'submenu-container sub-menu clearfix', 'menu_class' => 'ipf-sectionmenu' ) ); ?>
```

So reasonably straightforward.... except for just echoing out the menu title. Temporarily, I'm just echoing out the first item in the menu, which is almost always Home, so that works. Like so:

```
<?php
    $top = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Main');
    $name = $top[0]->post_title;
?>
<h3 id="left-subheader-mobile" class="purple-header"><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

When you filter `wp_nav_menu`, you get the nav menu arguments as second parameter `$args`. That's an object (a `stdClass`), set by WordPress while figuring out which menu to use, with an entry named `menu`. This is the whole nav menu object. Its title is in the entry `name`.

Here is a trick: you can pass *custom arguments* to `wp_nav_menu()`.

Let's say you are calling `wp_nav_menu()` like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(
    [
        'theme_location'  => 'secondary',
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'submenu-container sub-menu clearfix',
        'menu_class'      => 'ipf-sectionmenu',
        'heading'         => '<h3 id="left-subheader-mobile" class="purple-header">%s</h3>',
    ]
);
```

Now you have the HTML for the heading in the arguments, and it is available together with the actual menu title on the hook `wp_nav_menu`. All you have to do is bringing it together.

Dead simple, just add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', function( $nav_menu, $args ) {

    if ( empty ( $args->heading ) )
        return $nav_menu;

    $title   = esc_html( $args->menu->name );
    $heading = sprintf( $args->heading, $title );

    return $heading . $nav_menu;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this! 

I'm really not sure if it is doing what I asked (which probably wasn't clear), or if I'm just too obtuse to understand what's going on (likely).

I'm looking to get the title of the menu item that is attached to the page that I'm currently viewing, whatever that may be, so that I may then build the menu beneath that top level item.

For instance, my page may be: Events Nearby and it may be accessible from a custom menu with that item named 'Events'. I want to spit out 'Events' then display all the items in that custom menu under it.

So how do I do that with your function?

Comment: @oliverh72 Oh, then I misunderstood you. One post object can occur multiple times in one menu, each time with a different title. There is no direct relation between the object and the title(s). In this case you could filter `wp_nav_menu_objects` and search through all items, or create a custom walker.